# Retain valid workspace reference after project transfer.

Tags: r, project, directory-structure, project-organization

I've been working on a R project (projectA) that I want to hand over to a colleague, what would be the best way to handle workspace references in the scripts? To illustrate, let's say projectA consists of several R scripts that each read input and write output to certain directories (dirs). All dirs are contained within my local dropbox. The I/O part of the scripts look as follows:

```
# Script 1. 
# Give input and output names and dirs:
dat1Dir       <- "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/source1/"
dat1In        <- "foo1.asc"
dat2Dir       <- "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/source2/"
dat2In        <- "foo2.asc"
outDir        <- "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/output1/"
outName       <- "fooOut1.asc"
# Read data 
setwd(dat1Dir)
dat1          <- read.table(dat1In)
setwd(dat2Dir)
dat2          <- read.table(dat2In)
# do stuff with dat1 and dat2 that result in new data foo
# Write new data foo to file
setwd(outDir)
write.table(foo, outName)

# Script 2. 
# Give input and output names and dirs
dat1Dir       <- "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/output1/"
dat1In        <- "fooOut1.asc"
outDir        <- "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/output2/"
outName       <- "fooOut2.asc"
```

Etc. Each script reads and write data from/to file and subsequent scripts read the output of previous scripts. The question is: *how can I ensure that the directory-strings remain valid after transfer to another user?*

Let's say we copy the ProjectA folder, including subfolders, to another PC, where it is stored at, e.g., C:/Users/foo/my documents/. Ideally, I would have a function `FindDir()` that finds the location of the lowest common folder in the project, here "ProjectA", so that I can replace every directory string with:

```
dat1Dir       <- paste(FindDir(), "ProjectA/source1", sep= "")
```

So that:

```
# At my own PC
dat1Dir       <- paste(FindDir(), "ProjectA/source1", sep= "")
> "D:/Dropbox/ProjectA/source1/"

# At my colleagues PC
dat1Dir       <- paste(FindDir(), "ProjectA/source1", sep= "")
> "C:Users/foo/my documents/ProjectA/source1/"
```

Or perhaps there is a different way? Our work IT infrastructure currently does not allow using a shared disc. I'll put helper-functions in an 'official' R project (ie, hosted on [R forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/)), but I'd like to use scripts when many I/O parameters are required and because the code can easily be viewed and commented.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using relative directory paths. This is what I do for my R projects that I have in Dropbox and that I edit/run on both my Windows and OS X machines where the Dropbox folder is `D:/Dropbox` and `/Users/robin/Dropbox` respectively.

To do this, you'll need to

1. Set the current working directory in R (either in the first line of your script, or interactively at the console before running), using `setwd('/Users/robin/Dropbox;)` (see the [full docs for that command](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html)).
2. Change your paths to *relative paths*, which mean they just have the bit of the path from the current directory, in this case the `'ProjectA/source1'` bit if you've set your current directory to your Dropbox folder, or just `'source1'` if you've set your current directory to the ProjectA folder (which is a better idea).

Then everything should just work!

You may also be interested in an R library that I love called [ProjectTemplate](http://projecttemplate.net/) - it gives you really nice functionality for making self-contained projects for this sort of work in R, and they're entirely reproducible, moveable between computers and so on. I've written an [introductory blog post](http://blog.rtwilson.com/in-praise-of-projecttemplate-for-reproducible-research/) which may be useful.

Comment: Hi @robintw, thanks for your answer. I've been using R for about 5 years now but I've never realised that the path in `setwd()` can be relative to the current `getwd()`. I always just wrote them in full. So thanks for pointing this out, I'm sure this will work.